# What are some bases of the polynomial ring that expand positively in the basis of binomial coefficients?

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials

Some friends and I have a family of polynomials (in one variable) with rational coefficients and we would very much like a formula for them.  Grasping at straws, we computed many examples and wrote them in the basis of binomial coefficients.  Specifically, I mean the basis $\left\{\binom{x}{0},\binom{x}{1},\binom{x}{2},\ldots\right\}$ of the ring of rational polynomials over $x$.  We were surprised to find that our polynomials all expand positively and integrally in that basis.

That is, if one of our polynomials $p(x)$ of degree d is written as $\sum_{k=0}^da_k\binom{x}k$, each of the $a_k$ is a nonnegative integer.

We can't make much sense of the coefficients.  But we're wondering if the positivity of our polynomials in the binomial coefficients basis is a sort of "shadow" of some other stronger phenomenon.  Suppose there were some other basis $\{b_0(x),b_1(x),\ldots\}$ such that each $b_i(x)$ expands nonnegatively in the basis of binomial coefficients.  If our polynomials expand nonnegatively (and in some understandable way) in the basis $\{b_0(x),b_1(x),\ldots\}$, that's our desired formula.

If you're thinking "They're still grasping at straws", you're right.  But it can't hurt to ask:

What bases for the polynomial ring should we try?  Are there some well-known bases that expand positively in the binomial coefficients basis?

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but if you have a polynomial that expands nonnegatively into binomials, it is often the Hilbert polynomial of an interesting Cohen-Macaulay graded algebra.

Comment: Have you checked for unimodality/log-concavity? If your polynomials are of combinatorial nature you could try expressing them as chromatic polynomials of (insert adjective) graphs.

Comment: Sorry, I have been looking and these with cleared denominators too long, so I asked the question slightly wrong at first.  The polynomials have *rational* coefficients, but they expand as *nonnegative integer* combinations of binomial coefficients.  I edited the question.  I don't think this fundamentally alters what I'm asking, but sorry to get it wrong!

Comment: @SamHopkins:  Thanks, this is an angle I hadn't thought of.

Comment: @NathanReading: if they have integer coefficients in the binomial basis then they are integer-valued polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial), and the comment about thinking in terms of Hilbert series applies even more...

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi:  Yes, they seem to have unimodal coefficients.  We have not checked log-concavity.  As noted in my comment above, I had asked the question wrong initially.  The coefficients are rational, not integers, but the polynomials seem to take integer values when specialized to integers so they are "of a combinatorial nature" in that sense.  The chromatic polynomial idea is particularly intriguing, because the polynomials do indeed appear to evaluate to $0$ for integers below some threshold, and then increase monotonically, as one would expect for chromatic polynomials.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi:  Ah, but chromatic polynomials have integer coefficients, so my error in asking the question makes a difference.  Our polynomials don't have integer coefficients.  And they don't become monic when we clear denominators.

Comment: Why don't you provide more information about your polynomials?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე:  They come from a recursion, but writing the output of the recursion as a family of polynomials is, we think, new.  We can compute them, but we have so little understanding of the recursion that we only hope that there could be some nice formula because (1) it would improve our understanding of the recursion, (2) one hopes that the mathematical universe has hidden order, and (3) they have the one nice property described in the question.  For the purposes of this question, we can just think of these as polynomials from a black box with nice expansions in binomial coefficients.

Comment: Maybe at least you could show the first few, of lowest degrees, say, up to 10?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე:  My question is "What bases for the polynomial ring should we try? Are there some well-known bases that expand positively in the binomial coefficients basis?"  I think that's a reasonable question about research methods, and it may be of general interest.  Too many specifics of the polynomials would muddy the waters regarding this question about methods.  Also, I am not asking the question "Can anybody figure out these polynomials for us?", and I would rather not implicitly ask the mathoverflow community to analyze the polynomials.

Comment: It often helps to look at the polynomial obtained from the given polynomial $f(x)$ by a translation, $f(x-a)$. For example, it is often the shortest way to prove the irreducibility by applying some known criterion to a suitable translation.

Answer (score 8):

The basis $\binom{x}{0}$, $\binom{x+1}{1}$, $\binom{x+2}{2}$, $\dots$ has this property. More generally, if $i$ is a nonnegative integer then $\binom{x+i}{j}$ is a nonnegative linear combination of the $\binom{x}{k}$.

A useful basis for polynomials of degree at most $n$ with this property is $\binom{x}{n}$, $\binom{x+1}{n}$, $\dots$, $\binom{x+n}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks, we'll look at these possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

We conjecture that the coefficients of Jack polynomials can be expressed nicely in this basis, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.12763.pdf

Also, there is a close connection with rook polynomials and hit polynomials, as well as the relation between Ehrhart polynomials and the $h^*$-vector, which uses this type of polynomials.